# warning: initialization of 'int *' from ' int' makes pointer from integer without a cast, when assigning array to a int pointer

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, initialization, compound-literals

I was studying pointers and this is what i learned:-

```
int a = 23;
int *ptr = &a;

char b = 'b';
char *pnt = &b;

char *str = "string";
```

Value assigned to a pointer is an address. So i can't do `int *ptr = 7;` or `char *k = 'c';`. But i can do `char *str = "string";` because "string" is not a char but an array of some char values, as chars and pointers are quite similar to each other, So in above code if i print `printf("%p", str);` should print address saved in str which should be the address of starting address of string **(This is the 1st part where i want to know i am right or wrong)**

So in another way by doing `char *str = "string";` i am just creating an array of chars like `{'s','t','r','i','n','g'}`. **(maybe this is going to sound very stupid but that's what it is)** So i thought why not try `char *str = {'s','t','r','i','n','g'};`, i thought that `printf("%p\n", str)` will again give starting address of string but after getting some weired value and running `printf("%c", str)` returned 's' i found it is giving the very 1st element of array instead of address. and i tried same with int array and noticed a warning saying

```
int *array = {1,2,3};
```

> warning: initialization of 'int *' from ' int' makes pointer from integer without a cast

As per my understanding of this, compiler treating {1,2,3} as an int not as an array, i am not sure why but if i cast explicitly it is running fine like `int *array = (int[]){1,2,3}`. I am not sure why i need to tell explicitly but i think this is how compiler sees it

- after doing `int *array = {1,2,3};` compiler is getting an address of {1,2,3}.
- but when compiler sees there is an int at that address it is reading that int only
- and compiler sees it like `int *array = 1` not `int *array = {1,2,3}`

i don't know if my theory is right or not. If not please i want to know why this is happening and why doing `char *str = "string"` doesn't need any cast.

Comment: `{1,2,3}` is not an array.
`int foo[3] = {1,2,3}` is.

Comment: @Raildex i am feeling so stupid now.

Comment: so by doing `(int[]) {1,2,3}` i am not casting i am just declaring a new array

Comment: Yes, `(int[]) {1,2,3}` is a [*compound literal*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C string literals have character array types. For example the string literal `"string"` is stored in memory as the following array of the type `char[7]`:

```
{ 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', '\0' }
```

You can check this by using the following call

```
printf( "sizeof( \"string\" ) = %zu\n", sizeof( "string" ) );
```

Arrays used in expressions with rare exceptions are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements.

From the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
> operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
> expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
> expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
> element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
> has register storage class, the behavior is undefined

So in this declaration

```
char *str = "string";
```

the array that corresponds to the stored string literal by the compiler (usually in a string literal pool) is converted to pointer to its first element and the value of the pointer is assigned to the scalar object `str`.

`str` is not an array. `str` is a pointer.

The above declaration may be rewritten also the following way

```
char *str = &"string"[0];
```

This declaration

```
char *str = {'s','t','r','i','n','g'};
```

is incorrect. A scalar object may be initialized by a braced list that contains only one assignment expression.

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 11 The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression,
> optionally enclosed in braces. The initial value of the object is that
> of the expression (after conversion); the same type constraints and
> conversions as for simple assignment apply, taking the type of the
> scalar to be the unqualified version of its declared type.

You could write for example

```
char *str = { ( 's','t','r','i','n','g' )};
```

In this case within the braces there is a primary expression with the comma operator.  In fact this declaration is equivalent to

```
char *str = { 'g' };
```

and the compiler will issue a message that you are trying to initialize a pointer with an integer.

In this declaration

```
int *array = (int[]){1,2,3};
```

there is no casting. The construction `(int[]){1,2,3}` denotes a compound literal of the type `int[3]` and again the address of the first element of this array is assigned to the pointer `array`.

You may imagine the above declaration the following way

```
int compound_literal[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int *array = compound_literal;
```